# Special character wanted which prevents an Excel formula from changing its reference when the referenced cell is moved

Tags: excel

With the special character '$' I can prevent an Excel formula from changing its reference when the cell itself is copied (e.g '$A$1').
But is there also a special character that prevents an Excel formula from changing its reference when the referenced cell is moved?

Here's an example:

I have:
[image: example picture 1]

Now I move the cells 'A1:A3' down one row. So the formulas in the cells 'C1:C3' change:
[image: example picture 2]

But I don't want that the formulas in the cells 'C1:C3' change. They should remain unchanged:
[image: example picture 3]

Comment: You can use INDEX instead of referring directly to `A1`, `A2`, `A3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formula:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW(1:1))=INDEX(B:B,ROW(1:1)),"Same","Not same")
```

the formula always work, regardless of any column been delete besides columns `A` or `B`

Comment: Yes, I think this is the most elegant solution because here you can still see the columns and rows. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome. This formula is very useful particularly  when comparing things like two sets of `VbModules` that you need to delete or insert rows in one of the columns just to align it with the other.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to refer to A1, then you can't just use A1 as a reference, because, as you have seen, Excel will adjust that reference if rows are inserted above.

Instead, use `Index(A:A,1)` . That will always return the value from the first row of column A.

```
=if(index(A:A,1)=index(B:B,1),"same","not")
```

**Edit after comment:**  If this does not suit your purpose, maybe you need to redesign your spreadsheet so that the position of things does not change all the time. This looks like you are adding new data at the top of a list.

Excel works from top to bottom and things will be a lot easier if new data is added at the bottom of a list. You can always use other Excel tools to change the sort order if you want to have the data sorted in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Yes, this works for my example. But it's more a workaround and it's not so nice, because with 'INDEX' you have to type each formula (cells 'C1:C3') manually because you can't copy the formula by dragging down the bottom right corner of the cell 'C1'. Much more comfortable would be a special character that prevents the formula from changing its reference when the referenced cell is moved, like the special character "$" that prevents a formula from changing its reference when the cell itself is copied. But I'm afraid that this special character is not yet available.

Comment: Feel free to make this suggestion on https://excel.uservoice.com/ . This is just the way that Excel works.

Answer (score -1):

Use formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW(ZZ1))=INDEX(B:B,ROW(ZZ1)),"Same","Not same")
```

and copy down.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks pretty nice. But as written below, this is rather a workaround. Much more comfortable would be a special character that prevents the formula from changing its reference when the referenced cell is moved, like the special character "$" that prevents a formula from changing its reference when the cell itself is copied. But I'm afraid that this special character is not yet available. Remark: We can also use 'ROW(Z1)' instead of 'ROW(ZZ1)', can't we?

Comment: Using Row(some cell) is more work for Excel than using just the number you want to use. But more importantly, using `Row(ZZ1)` will change to `Row(ZZ2)` if a row is inserted before Row 1, so the whole concept of using Index() with a fixed number won't work if you use Row(cell address) instead of the number.

Comment: @Seeky Yes, you can use any cell address from the first row as long as that cell is not touched.

Comment: @teylyn First, I answered the question ```how to prevent an Excel formula from changing its reference when the referenced cell is moved``` and the formula I propose does it. Second, if an entire row is inserted, then the user is also likely to expect the formula to move down with all of its references. So please cancel your downvote.

Comment: First, it isn't my downvote, so there's nothing I can do about that. Second, your approach will break if the user inserts a row above ZZ1, too, so it is not very robust.

Comment: Since the special character I was looking for doesn't seem to exist yet, my problem can be solved most elegantly with the formula `=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW(Z1))=INDEX(B:B,ROW(Z1)),"Same","Not same")`. Many thanks for your great help. PS: I still don't understand why you suggested `=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW(ZZ1))=INDEX(B:B,ROW(ZZ1)),"Same","Not same")`, which also works, but does the same thing as the formula mentioned above.

Comment: @Seeky I have practically never encountered a table with 700+ columns, so I assume that in 99% of cases the ZZ column will not be touched and this formula will work correctly.

Comment: Okay, now I got your point; if the column 'Z' resp. 'ZZ' is deleted, the formula no longer works and the chance that the column 'ZZ' is deleted is much smaller than that the column 'Z' is deleted. So I think we should use `=IF(INDEX(A:A,ROW())=INDEX(B:B,ROW()),"Same","Not same")` to avoid this problem at all.